# Assume that for all $x\in A$ there exists a neighborhood $S$ of $x$ such that $f$ is constant in $S\cap A$. Then $f$ is constant in $A$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f:A\subset X\to Y$ be a continouos in the connected set $A$. Assume that for all $x\in A$ there exists a neighborhood $S$ of $x$ such that $f$ is constant in $S\cap A$. Then $f$ is constant in $A$.

Any suggestions to prove that $f$ is constant in $A$.

Comment: This is actually true as long as $A$ is _connected_. The term for such an $f$ is "[locally constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_constant_function)".

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Fix any $x_0$ in your domain and look at the set of $x$ in your domain for which $f(x) = f(x_0)$. Is this set open? Is it closed? What does that tell you?